# How can I develop an iPhone application in Perl?

Tags: ios, iphone, perl

Could someone provide a good link to book about how to develop iPhone application with the Perl programming language?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Why would you want to use Perl? You'd miss out on everything the iPhone SDK gives you, and you wouldn't be in the iTunes App Store.

If you are trying to use Perl because it's the only language you know, just bite the bullet and learn Objective-C. Use the right tool for the right job. Despite how much I enjoy working in Perl, I don't think it's the answer to every problem.

However, if you did want to use the Perl route, you could use it to drive an HTML-based app. You end up installing a mini-website with local storage, etc, on the iPhone. [Building iPhone Apps with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript](http://building-iphone-apps.labs.oreilly.com/) is in O'Reilly's Open Feedback Publishing System, so you could see how to do that for free. Perl might be a tiny, server-side component of that.

Comment: Wow. Coming from one of the known masters of Perl, that is cool advice!

Answer (score 9):

Generally Perl is not a good choice here. Without jailbreaking the iPhone, you will need to compile perl into a static library and link it against your byte-compiled code (or build a small app that glues the two together). This seems a lot of work for little benefit, since Perl has no bindings to the various Cocoa and UI elements you'll need to manage your run loop. Why do you want to use perl here?

Jailbroken development is outside the license agreement. Searching "perl iphone" will give you several links on the subject, but I really can't go much further into that.

Comment: Which langaues you suggest instead ?

Comment: @dan: The usual choice is Objective-C.

Comment: Why?  Because it's Perl, duh!  :)

Comment: @Rob Napier: I am really sorry, somehow I did something that made your answer to be down-voted. This was really unintended and I apologize for that. Now I am told that I cannot change my down-vote until the post is edited: if you can just add a blank line to it or whatever, maybe it will work and I will promptly change the down-vote. Apologies.

Answer (score 6):

If you insist on Perl, relax your constraint on it being an iPhone "application". Make it a web application targeted for the iPhone!

**Pros**

1. You can use all the Perl you want! Even [Catalyst](http://www.catalystframework.org/)!
2. Any version of Perl you want, in your own configuration.
3. Cross platform with other mobile/Internet devices.
4. Way easier to deploy updates and bugfixes.

**Cons**

1. Requires a constant internet connection.
2. Is accessible outside of the iPhone enviroment.
3. Isn't in the iTunes store.
4. Tradition breaker.

Comment: There are also modules to do Apple Push notifications (APNS) on the CPAN.

Comment: Why is it a tradition breaker? Many of my favorite iPhone apps are just frontends to websites. Also, you can still put the client in the iTunes App Store.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean backend to a iPhone application (via XMLRPC), then we are all behind you I believe.

Answer (score -1):

I think Perl is a fine choice for writing a web based mobile app.

mate it with one of these tools for creating a native look and feel for a variety of mobile platforms:

http://code.google.com/p/iui/

http://www.phonegap.com/

http://www.jqtouch.com/

my 2 award winning iPhone mashups run on Perl :)

http://imoviemash.com

http://imusicmash.com

Al